# FileNotFoundException on existing file

Tags: laravel, apache, permissions

I have a symbolic link to another folder where I store files. Everything works ok as far as directory scanning is concerned. The scan itself is done by a scheduled job and always works fine.

However, when I try to download a file that is stored in that directory, It throws a FileNotFoundException despite It actually exists. I suspect that It has something to do with the apache user permissions, because I've found that if I try to `dd` a scandir of the symlink (from a controller), I get a `Permission denied` error.

The folder pointed by the symbolic link is owned by `cloud:cloud` and I've added the user `stage` to that `cloud` group to give It access.

This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # HTTPS Redirect
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

The symlink is gitignored and the user who runs the scheduled job is `stage`.
I'm using php-fpm as well.

Comment: Do you use .htaccess - share it here. Is your symlink gitignored - yes it should. Who (what user on the machine) runs sheduled jobs? How did you set up cron etc... share it all here. Do you use php-fpm and fastcgi or mod_php?

Comment: @Kyslik The symlink is gitignored and the user who runs the scheduled job is `stage`. I've added more info.

Comment: What permissions does the directory you speak of have? 0664?